# Search between patterns in a file with multiple occurrences

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I am trying to search between patterns. I know `sed` will do it if it is a single occurrence.

Here is the file:

```
Iowa<br>
data1<br>
data2<br>
Montana<br>
junk1<br>
junk2<br>
junk3<br>
Iowa<br>
data3<br>
data4<br>
Arizona<br>
junk5<br>
junk6<br>
```

I am trying to get the content between `Iowa` and `Montana`.

So, I do `sed -ne '/Iowa/,/Montana/p` `$file` and see a result like this:

```
Iowa<br>
data1<br>
data2<br>
Montana<br>
Iowa<br>
data3<br>
data4<br>
Arizona<br>
junk5<br>
junk6<br>
```

Not sure why it prints `Iowa - Arizona` and beyond. Is there a way to print the content between `Iowa` and `Montana` only?

As a temporary workaround, I am printing all and taking the 1st occurrence.

Comment: the last awk answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/4082052) fits... also suggest to add your expected output to know if you need `Iowa` and `Montana` also in output or only lines between them... also make it clear if your input can contain multiple or only one `Iowa...Montana`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were wanting to use perl, this one-liner does the job:

`perl -ne 'last if /Montana/; print if $i; $i++ if /Iowa/' $file`

output:

```
data1
data2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flip flop operator

```
perl -ne 'next if (1 ../Iowa/); last if(/Montana/); print;' input.txt
```